# What does this.getClass() return during construction?

Tags: java

What does Java `this.getClass()` return during object construction, e.g., when called from a constructor or field initializer expression? Is it safe to expect the most derived class to be returned or not?

Comment: `this.getClass()` can only possibly return the run-time type of the object (the class that was actually instantiated; the "most derived class"). Even if the members haven't all been initialised because construction hasn't completed, it is still an object of that particular type.

Comment: @khelwood: In C++ the run time type of an object changes during construction (and destruction), so I am checking whether this is not also the case in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of several places where you can observe the difference between how constructing an object works in the Java language versus in the Java virtual machine.

In JVM bytecode, constructing an object of a given type is a single instruction and thus atomic. At no time is the object itself an object of a different type, like a supertype. However, this object will not yet have been "constructed". At the bytecode level, the constructor is a special method named `<init>`, which can set fields and otherwise manipulate the object which already exists.

The compiler assembles any actual constructor, plus the field initializers and instance initializer blocks into the `<init>` method. The first operation of `<init>` is normally to call the corresponding `<init>` method declared on the supertype. So the initializers get run in order from supertypes to subtypes. However, when the supertype `<init>` method is executing, the object itself is already of the type it will be once complete; therefore `getClass()` will return that type, and the value returned by `getClass()` will not change depending on where it is called.

From the standpoint of the Java language, this is (mostly) a moot point, since if any of the `<init>` methods involved throws an exception, the object is normally immediately eligible for garbage collection. However, there are a few cases where you can cause a partially-constructed object to become visible to another thread, in which case you can observe objects with inconsistent states. You can also intentionally create an object without running its `<init>` by using the (intentionally undocumented) methods of `sun.misc.Unsafe` on a JVM that exposes that class.